# Where can I find D4 dice that are truncated tetrahedrons?

Tags: dice, reference

The points are truncated (so it technically has 8 sides). The die cannot come to rest on these small, truncated, sides, which have the opposite large side number printed on their face.

These seem like a much better design for D4s, does anyone know where I can get some?

Here's the sort of thing I'm talking about:

[image]

I'm looking for something less ornate and thus much cheaper ;)

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure if you cast enough Magic Missiles, those dice WILL come up on the small side. My steampunk polyset has a D4 that can balance on the points, and we joke that when it does it'll be a 5! (Set is not cheap, but available here: http://www.shapeways.com/model/636461/steampunk-gear-dice-set.html?li=productBox-search

Comment: You can get 8-sided d4 dice (i.e. numbered 1 through 4 twice), that's probably a cheaper option if you're just after a d4 that actually rolls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can just select a cheaper material on that 3D printing site. So, whilst it's still more expensive than the usual 50c for a die, given that these type of dice don't seem to be as common as I expected it seems like a reasonable solution in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Pick up a bag of Chessex Blank d4s. (It's product number CHX29301, ask your Favorite Local Game Store). Grab a Dremel or Power Sander and take off the points. Then sharpie (or carve) the numbers in by hand. That's going to be your cheap route, unless someone decides to kickstart a project like this. Certainly cheaper than buying 3d printed versions.

Comment: Modifying the dices by hand will change the weight distribution and therefore the probabilities. I do not think, this is a welcome effect...

Comment: While this is true, chances are d4s are not going to be used anywhere that money is on the line, so it probably won't be a big deal if "3" comes up a bit more frequently than it should, and "4" slightly less. Additionally as these would be designed by hand, unless some effort was put into it, chances are slim that inequality would be intentional.

Comment: Are you talking about [these](http://www.chessex.com/Dice/Specialty%20Dice/4_sided.htm)? Product number seems to be XQ0004 or XQ0060. The link also has 8 and 12-sided d4s.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm a nerd...if I tried to use a power sander I'd probably cut both my arms off.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about Crystal Caste dice.  I don't think recommending a particular store is in scope for a stack exchange answer, but the brand name should be plenty to go by.

Comment: Who'da thunk? Crystal Caste won a lawsuit against monopoly's owners over use of their "patented" crystal shape. Talk about an obvious invention.

Comment: Those are barrel dice. That's not what I'm looking for. I'll add a picture.